# Execute Python Program line-by-line automatically

Tags: python, selenium, line-by-line

I'm doing a python script with selenium. To do tests I use command promp, this way i know if my line of command is working without needing to execute the program over and over to correct line by line. The thing is, i need a way to automatically start this lines so i don't need to keep retype it everytime i want to do some tests.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=options
```

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, running `python -m pdb <yourscript.py>` should open the  [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and allow you to step through.  Each line is run by entering `n` and returning.

Comment: Short and precise, gem of an answer.